# What determines the default initial view of a Google map?

Tags: android, gps, maps, google-maps-android-api-2

When you open a new instance of a Google Map view in an Android application, in the second before it switches to the latitude, longitude coordinates that you specify it shows a default location. For example, if I specify coordinates in Guyana, it might initially show a view of my local area before switching there. I've tried turning off all location services for my phone, wiping my location history from Google, changing my Google account to belong to Guyana as much as possible, etc. but it still shows my local area for an instant before it switches there.

I've come up with the following theories, but I'd be glad if someone could shed additional light on the subject:

1. The default view is determined by your IP address - this actually doesn't seem to be entirely correct, as a coworker in Guyana tried to open the application and still saw our local area for a second before it switched over.
2. The default view is determined by the default domain Google associates with your Google account. For example, if you are in the UK then your default search is *google.co.uk* and perhaps your default view is also determined by that? If this is the case then I'd appreciate knowing how to change the association between your Google account and a particular domain.
3. The default view is determined by the address that you entered into Google Wallet as your billing address(?)

Note, that the default view is apparently **not** determined by location history - if my coworker in Guyana logs out and into the application a dozen times, he still sees our local area every single time (for a second before it switches over).

Comment: Here is the - at least somehow related - documentation on how to [define the initial state of a Google MapView](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#configure_initial_state) being used in some application.